# Processing a button press from another class

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

I'm creating a large program to track finances. Because of this, I've cleaned up my code by positioning elements in other classes, then using aggregation to implement them in my main program. The only problem is I've started to work on interaction and handling button presses, but I can't register any button presses normally. Here's clean sample code to highlight the problem.

**Main Execution Class**

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class testingButton extends Application{
   private buttonClass add;

   @Override
  public void start(Stage stage){
      add = new buttonClass();

      Pane root = new Pane();
      root.getChildren().addAll(add.getB());

      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 150,150);
      stage.setTitle("Testing Visual elements");
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
   }
   public void processButtonPress(ActionEvent event){
       if(event.getSource() == add.getB()){
           System.out.println("testing");
       }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
      launch(args);
   }
}
```

**Aggregate button class**

```
 import javafx.scene.control.Button;

 public class buttonClass{
   private Button b;

   public buttonClass(){
      b = new Button("Button");
      b.setLayoutX(50);
      b.setLayoutY(50);
   }

   public Button getB(){
      return b;
   }
}
```

How can I get the button press to register? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1. I can't see any line of code registering an action (`setOnAction()`)for your button. 2. It's likely that `event.getSource()` returns an object, which you are comparing to a `Button`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code you need...

you need to apply an actionevent to the button not try to get a button from actionevent

```
public class JavaApplication3 extends Application {

ButtonClass add;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    add = new ButtonClass();

    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.getChildren().add(add);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 150, 150);
    stage.setTitle("Testing Visual elements");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    add.setOnAction((javafx.event.ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("Button pressed");
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

and the button class

```
public class ButtonClass extends Button {

private Button b;

public ButtonClass() {
    b = new Button("Button");
    b.setLayoutX(50);
    b.setLayoutY(50);
}
```